# Android Array Out of Bound Exception

Tags: java, android, arrays, webview

I have built a Android App thats has a WebView to show a mobile website within the app.
I have started to get this exception on one device particularly
This issue is not seen on other devices.

I went through the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3.1_r1/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.java#773) and it looks like an issue with Android. Can any one help me understand that if we can do anything else in the app to suppress this exception

**Note**: In the stack trace, there is nothing related to the app code

```
AndroidAppCrashDump {"brand":"samsung","model":"GT-S6312","sdk":16,"android":"4.1.2","appVersion":"1.1.15","manufacturer":"samsung"}----java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1109619192 at 
 java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:855) at 
 android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.clearMotionHistory(ViewDragHelper.java:773) at 
 android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.cancel(ViewDragHelper.java:499) at 
 android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(ViewDragHelper.java:1031) at 
 android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(DrawerLayout.java:868) at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877) at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237) at 
 an droid.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979) at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237) at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979) at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237) at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979) at 
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2177) at 
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1482) at 
 android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2469) at 
 android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:260) at 
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2125) at 
 android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7414) at 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3523) at 
 android.vi ew.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3455) at 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4565) at 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4543) at 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4647) at 
 android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171) at 
 android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) at 
 android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125) at 
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124) at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963) at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) at 
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to `WebView`. It happens in the `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: This looks similar to this bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=103888